# Creating SQL Session state store

Tags: asp.net

Implemented the SqlSessionStateStore by inheriting from SessionStateStoreProviderBase. Created the dll and placed the dll in the bin folder (as im not able to register it into GAC as im using MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express).

And add the below Session State  Configuration setting in the web.config.

```
 <sessionState
      cookieless="true"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
      mode="Custom"       
      customProvider="SqlSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SqlSessionProvider"
            type="Sample.AspNet.Session.SqlSessionStateStore"
             connectionString="SqlConnenctionString"             
             writeExceptionToEventLog="false"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Now im getting this error.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Sample.AspNet.Session.SqlSessionStateStore'.
Source Error:

```
Line 15:       <providers>
Line 16:         <add name="SqlSessionProvider"
Line 17:              type="Sample.AspNet.Session.SqlSessionStateStore"
Line 18:              connectionString="SqlConnenctionString"             
Line 19:              writeExceptionToEventLog="false"/>
```

Can any one help me with the reason for this error.

Comment: why did you put the implementation of SqlSessionStateStore in a separate dll?

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of being obvious

1. Have you got a reference to where Sample.AspNet.Session.SqlSessionStateStore lives
2. Could you need to qualify the namespace further and that's why it can't find it
3. I'm sure you haven't done this but if you've copied the code from a reference site then it could be that you've just kept the Sample.AspNet.Session.SqlSessionStateStore ref in when it doesn't exist anywhere and in fact it's just boilerplate code

Basically it can't find a reference to your custom provider - so you need to be sure that the website can see it

Comment: That the reason i copied the dll to bin folder and also i have set the reference.Even then it is giving same error.